# Open Silverlight Project with Button Click Event

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Is it possible to open a Silverlight Project within a button click event of another Silverlight Project?
i.e Silverlight Project A button click event to open Silverlight Project B.

Comment: Where would you want to open the SL Project B? In another page, inside a web brush, on a html host?

Answer (score 0):

From Silverlight you have control of the web page where you are hosting Silverlight Project A, even of javascript (so you can call a javascript method form within your Silverlight project A).

Also, you can host several Silverlight objects inside a web page, for an example, if you have a web project besides your Silverlight project inside your solution, you can open the .html file from this project and see the "" tag. That tag says that inside that page should be a silverlight object, so you can have any number of " ... " tags pointing to same number of silverlight projects (or project instances)

Here is an example:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/alex_golesh/archive/2008/07/10/quick-silverlight-tip-communicating-between-two-silverlight-objects-on-a-single-page.aspx